# Pagination using retrofit to fetch next 10 items from API on scrolling in android

Tags: android, pagination, retrofit

Pagination using retrofit to fetch next 10 items from API on scrolling in android

Comment: if you are using recycler view then use Recyclerview.addonScrollListener

Comment: Load first 10 data from the server and then when you reach bottom of your list find last visible item's id(if your backend is providing you some id for every data) in your service call and then add another 10 data to your existing list and on and on for other data..

Comment: Why did you add this line 2 times? rv.addOnScrollListener(); and as per your code review, I think there's some issue with your custom EndlessScroll

Comment: Okay not an issue, just make sure that EndlessScroll is returning proper position when you reach at the bottom of your list

Comment: Put log in your scroll listener and then check for the correct position, else let me know i'll try my best to help you

Comment: So you mean to say that, counter is increasing properly but not making effect in your BASE URL, right ?

Comment: Okay, now when you call loadNextPage method, you pass index value in there, but where do you use that value ? You have to service again with that index value as parameter after that you'll get next 10 data

Comment: Yes, you've to pass that value as parameter in URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your recycleview ScrollListener

```
private static final int PAGE_START = 0;
private boolean isLoading = false;  
private boolean isLastPage = false;   
private int TOTAL_PAGES = 3; //your total page
private int currentPage = PAGE_START;





rv.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        protected void loadMoreItems() {
            isLoading = true;
            currentPage += 1;
            loadApi(currentPage); //pass page number as parameter in your api calls
        }

        @Override
        public int getTotalPageCount() {
            return TOTAL_PAGES;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLastPage() {
            return isLastPage;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoading() {
            return isLoading;
        }
    });


}
```

more details refer [Pagination Android RecyclerView](http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-pagination-tutorial-getting-started-recyclerview/)

Comment: Diyvesh, have u checked this one

Answer (score 2):

instead,

for pagination if you are using simple listview with BaseAdapter,
then you may follow below code.

Use 2 arrayList for paginataion.
one is to load all listview items(allDataList), and one is to set 10 items in adapter(paginationList).

first load all data in allDataList by using retrofit.

```
public static int itemsCount = 10; 
     //i need pagination of 10 records, so here i passed 10, you may increase this no. here as your requirement.

ArrayList<User_pojo> allDataList, paginationList;
Adapter_UserList adapter;
ListView listViewUser;
View footerView;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
int lastItem,preLast;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = this;
        listViewUser = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewUser);

        allDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        paginationList = new ArrayList<>();
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        footerView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.load_more_view, null);
        listViewUser.addFooterView(footerView);

        Call_api();

        listViewUser.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

       @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

           lastItem = (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount);
            if (lastItem == totalItemCount) {
                if (preLast != lastItem) {
                    //to avoid multiple calls for last item

                    preLast = lastItem;

                    footerView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    footerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            itemsCount += 10;
                            LoadMoreList();
                            listViewUser.setSelection(lastItem - 1); //to display more loaded records @ current displayed position.
                        }
                    }, 1500);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      LoadMoreList();

    }

public interface AppService{

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("getUserList")
    Call<User_pojo> getUserList(@FieldMap(encoded = true) Map<String, String> map);

}       

void Call_api() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://your_api_url_here.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    Call<User_pojo> call = retrofit.create(AppService.class).getUserList(getUserMap());

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User_pojo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User_pojo> call, Response<User_pojo> response) {
            Log.e("Response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
            if (response.body().getResponse().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                allDataList = response.body().getData();
                Log.e("size", allDataList.size() + "");
                LoadMoreList();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User_pojo> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            t.getMessage();
            Log.e("Failed", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

    private void LoadMoreList() {
    try {
        Log.e("size", String.valueOf(allDataList.size()));
        if (allDataList.size() >= itemsCount) {
            paginationList.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
                paginationList.add(allDataList.get(i));
            }
            Log.e("paginationList_Size", String.valueOf(paginationList.size()));
            adapter = new Adapter_UserList(context, paginationList);
        } else {
            adapter = new Adapter_UserList(context, allDataList);
            listViewUser.removeFooterView(footerView); // loaded all list then simply remove footerView.
        }

        if (footerView != null)
            footerView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        listViewUser.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {

    }
}


private Map<String, String> getUserMap() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("uid", "001");
    map.put("token", "5526");

    Log.e("logs", map.toString());
    return map;
}
```

hope this help.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do with recyclerview

Comment: can you please share Adapter_UserList

Answer (score 0):

Use below EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener class.

```
 public abstract class EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
        // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
        // before loading more.
        private int visibleThreshold = 5;
        // The current offset index of data you have loaded
        private int currentPage = 0;
        // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
        private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
        // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
        private boolean loading = true;
        // Sets the starting page index
        private int startingPageIndex = 0;

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

        public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
            this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
        }

        public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(GridLayoutManager layoutManager) {
            this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
            visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
        }

        public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager) {
            this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
            visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
        }

        public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {
            int maxSize = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
                } else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                    maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
                }
            }
            return maxSize;
        }

        // This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
        // We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
        // but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = 0;
            int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();

            if (mLayoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
                int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
                // get maximum element within the list
                lastVisibleItemPosition = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);
            } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
                lastVisibleItemPosition = ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
                lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
                    doPullToRefresh();
                }
            }

            // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
            // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
            if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
                this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
                this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
                if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                    this.loading = true;
                }
            }
            // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
            // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
            // number and total item count.
            if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            }

            // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
            // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
            // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
            // threshold should reflect how many total columns there are too
            if (!loading && (lastVisibleItemPosition + visibleThreshold) > totalItemCount) {
                currentPage++;
                onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount, view);
                loading = true;
            }
        }

        // Call this method whenever performing new searches
        public void resetState() {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = 0;
            this.loading = true;
        }

        // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
        public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view);

        public abstract void doPullToRefresh();

    }
```

Initialise recycler view and add scroll listener to the recycler view as:

```
scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(llm) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
                fetchNextTenRecords(page);
            }

            @Override
            public void doPullToRefresh() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` and `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` you can find index of the last visible item. If the index equals to the total items count - 1 you can consider it as the end of the list and load the next page.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
        {
            int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            if (!loading && lastVisibleItemPosition == totalItemCount - 1) {
                loading = true;
                currentPage = currentPage + 1;
                if (!dynamicPages.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    loadMoreData(currentPage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, please add a minimum description of what you did.

Comment: Please provide the proper explanation of the question.